# Weird caching in a Webview vscode extension

Tags: webview, visual-studio-code, browser-cache, vscode-extensions

My vscode extension includes a main.js, similar to the webview-sample in vscode-extension-samples project. Changing the file, such as a string in a console.log() message, does not change what is output in the Console tab of the Developer Tools debugger. This is the Developer Tools window launched from the Extension Development Host when debugging the extension. The main.js in the ./out directory of the project is updated. I have even deleted the ./out directory and rebuilt. The update version of the file is created. Now here is the really weird part, going to the Sources tab in the Developer Tools, and selecting main.js shows the updated version of the file, but the Console tab is showing the old message. Ideas? Is this a bug? Where could the old main.js file be hiding/cached?

Comment: Try [debugging the webview itself](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/webview#_inspecting-and-debugging-webviews). Do you see the correct script version loaded?

Comment: That is the weird part. The debugger (in the Sources tab) shows the correct (updated) version, but the console output (in the Console tab) is of the older version.of the file. Even more freaky is I have essentially grep'ed the entire user's directory, AppData and sibling directories, including hidden directories for instances of the old string, and cannot find where it might be cached. I also searched all the hard drives for instances of main.js (there are lots) looking for where it might be cached. Nothing.

Comment: Another data point is I added a console logging statement in the webview-sample (cat coding) project's main.js. It showed up in the debugger. Changed it. It was updated and the updated message was displayed in the debugger console. There is not much difference between my project and the sample.  I do have an npm postcompile task that copies some additional .js files (transpiled from typescript) copied into same directory as the main.js, but that is it. There is launch.js syntax for disabling caching, but the github issue does not have a complete example.